# ubuntu 19.04 works in recovery mode, but not in normal boot

Tags: nvidia, xorg

Whenever, I use the recovery mode and just enter "resume", the xwindows work. However, if I use the kernel image without recovery mode directly, X does not start. 
In the Xorg.0.log file I see that the nvidia drivers failed to load. 
But then how is the system working in the recovery mode?

```
[     8.031] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration$
[     8.370] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:3e9b:1025:125e rev 0, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072$
[     8.370] (--) PCI: (1@0:0:0) 10de:1c8c:1025:1260 rev 161, Mem @ 0xa3000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288$
[     8.370] (II) LoadModule: "glx"$
[     8.370] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so$
[     8.376] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"$
[     8.376] >--compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0$
[     8.376] >--ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0$
[     8.376] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"$
[     8.376] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia$
[     8.376] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)$
[     8.376] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0$
[     8.376] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1$
[     8.376] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2$
[     8.376] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout$
[     8.376] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"$
[     8.377] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so$
[     8.377] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"$
[     8.377] >--compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4$
[     8.377] >--Module class: X.Org Video Driver$
[     8.377] >--ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0$
[     8.377] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"$
[     8.377] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia$
[     8.377] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)$
[     8.377] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"$
[     8.377] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so$
[     8.377] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"$
[     8.377] >--compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0$
[     8.377] >--Module class: X.Org Video Driver$
[     8.377] >--ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0$
[     8.377] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"$
[     8.377] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so$
[     8.377] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"$
[     8.377] >--compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0$
[     8.377] >--Module class: X.Org Video Driver$
[     8.377] >--ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0$
[     8.377] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms$
[     8.377] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev$
[     8.377] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa$
[     8.382] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory$
[     8.382] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting$
[     8.382] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory$
[     8.382] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"$
[     8.382] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"$
[     8.382] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so$
[     8.382] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"$
[     8.382] >--compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2$
[     8.382] >--ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0$
```

EDit:

By disabling nvidia in /etc/modprobe.d, the booting also works now in the normal mode. However, I do not understand, what drivers are loaded. Following is the output of lshw

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: ok, first thing, forget `lshw` in terms of info and run `sudo lspci -s $(lspci | grep VGA | cut -d ' ' -f1) -vv`  instead and post the output. The last two lines of that comman will also list the kernel module currently in use by your video adapter.

Comment: the command shows the kernel module i915 for intel and nvidiafb, nouveau for nvidia. But still `lsmod | grep nvidia` returns nothing.  `prime-select query` shows nvidia. How do I confirm what display driver is currently being used?

Comment: The ` Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)$ ` line might be related to a linking error. Please first run `sudo find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'nvidia*.ko*'